# Why are some methods using the Boolean class and not the primitive type?

Tags: java, methods, parameters, boolean, boxing

I was looking around the Android framework documentation, and one thing caught my eye. The [`setIs24HourView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#setIs24HourView%28java.lang.Boolean%29) method of [`TimePicker`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html) uses the *wrapper class* [`Boolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html), not the primitive type `boolean`.

I was just wondering, could there be a specific reason to use the wrapper class there? Can it do any benefit or could it just be a developer accidentally pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> a little too long? And could/should it be reported as a bug (indeed an extremely tiny one, because of auto-boxing, but still one)?

Comment: I'd be interested to know how it handled being passed `null`.  Sometimes methods are written with wrapper types instead of primitive types in case being passed `null` is possible / should be treated specially.

Comment: In the other hand, I'm surprised that `getCurrentHour` returns an `Integer` instead of an `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you want to use `Boolean` instead of `boolean` when your API allows the "unknown" state, for which you could allow passing `null`.

In this case, however, there is no "unknown" state, because [the corresponding getter is declared with the primitive `boolean`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#is24HourView%28%29):

```
public boolean is24HourView ()
```

I would definitely report this as a bug.

Comment: Great! I actually tried it out, `null` crashes with a `NullPointerException`, unsurprisingly. Reporting a bug.